# Delete rows base on the input box date

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with specific macro: I have excel spreadsheet where in column "K" I have both blank cells and cells with dates. I need to create a macro which  will delete all the rows where date is before input box date. But I also needs is to keep blank.
I tried multiple examples that I found online and nothing works.
Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far ([edit] your question and add the code). Then tell where exactly you got stuck or where you got errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. We are here to help with specific programming problems. Please post your best attempt and explain what isn't working.

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it 

looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, just set `ws` to whatever worksheet you have your dates in

```
Sub datechecker()

    Dim inputBoxText As String
    Dim inputBoxDate As Date
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws    

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
    inputBoxText = InputBox("Please enter a Date:", "Date Input Box", "Type Here", 10, 10)

    If IsDate(inputBoxText) Then
        inputBoxDate = CDate(inputBoxText)
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a correct date"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo Handler
    For row = 1 To lastRow
        If Len(.Range("K" & row).Value) > 0 Then
            If inputBoxDate > CDate(.Range("K" & row).Value) Then
                .Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete
                row = row - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    End With

    Exit Sub

Handler:
    MsgBox "Please make sure cells are formatted to date"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It worked!!

Comment: @InnaG No problem. Could you "accept" the answer so I can get points :) lol

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are correct, next time please provide what you have tried so far instead of just asking us to do all the work.

However, this is my approach to this problem:
1) in D2:D24 I have random dates between 2016 and 31-12-2017. let's say you want to delete all rows that have a date before 01-03-2017. In column E I have added the numerical value of the date values, which means 01-03-2017 = 42795. 
You could use the next macro:

```
Sub cleardatesmallerthan()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 24
      If Sheets(1).Range("e" & i).Value <= 42795 Then
      Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value = ""
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: this question is very likely to be closed soon, so your answer will be lost